# changing the background of a page with a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, background-color, rgb

So far, I have been able to make a variable that will store the hexcode, but I can't figure out how to use that variable in order to change the background color to that color. This is my code so far:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(${redhex}, ${greenhex}, ${bluehex})';
```

where `redhex`, `greenhex`, and `bluehex` are all variables that the user can change for the RGB. I think that part of the issue might be that I have another variable in my code named `rgb`?

Comment: You need to use backticks in order to use variables within a string rather than normal single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to interpolate other values inside the string.
So in your case, it might be

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${redhex}, ${greenhex}, ${bluehex})`;
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you could also use this website https://www.rgbtohex.net/

It is a tool I use some times to convert RGB into simple hex values this will replace

`rgb(${redhex}, ${greenhex}, ${bluehex})`  with `${rgbHexCode}`

Resulting in
document.body.style.backgroundColor = `${rgbHexCode}`;

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you, the variable is hexcode, but then, rgb doesn't take hex values. Rgb takes base 10 values from 0 to 255. Be sure to check if you are sending the right type of value